# PL/SQL - where to update and where to rollback

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm pretty new to PL/SQL and I have to work with it a lil bit. I had to make some functions which are pretty similar. I simplified it for this question.

I got 2 tables (called them TABLE1, TABLE2 in this example) which have some data. I have to trim, validate the data and insert it into other tables.

TABLE1 -> TABLE3
TABLE2 -> TABLE4

TABLE1 has some orders, while TABLE2 has several positions for each order. As I said its simplfied so I haven't posted things like the exception or the open/close cursors etc. Atm it works like this but I don't think this structure is somewhere near "best-practise" but I didn't found any PL/SQL code on the web which covered this problem, though it must be something pretty common.

COMMIT could be at the end of the outer loop I guess, maybe its even after the whole function.

So could you tell me if its okay like this or completely stupid and what I should/could change and why. I don't wanna get used to a 'bad' codingstyle so I wanna learn it the right way while I'm a beginner at it.

Heres the simplified code:

```
BEGIN
    SAVEPOINT SAVE_Stufe_5;
    LOOP
        SAVEPOINT SAVE_LOOP;
        FETCH CURSOR1 INTO RECORD1;
        EXIT WHEN CURSOR1%NOTFOUND OR CURSOR1%NOTFOUND IS NULL;
        vError  := 0;
        RECORD1 := CURSOR1;
        -- DATAVALIDATION (vError will be the Errorcode)
        IF (vError = 0) THEN
            retcode := InsertTABLE3(RECORD1);
            IF (retcode != DATABASE_OK) THEN
                ROLLBACK TO SAVE_LOOP;
            END IF;
        END IF;
        LOOP
            FETCH CURSOR2 INTO CURSOR2;
            EXIT WHEN CURSOR2%NOTFOUND OR CURSOR2%NOTFOUND IS NULL OR vError != 0 OR retcode != DATABASE_OK;
            RECORD2 := CURSOR2;
            -- DATAVALIDATION (vError will be the Errorcode)
            IF (vError = 0) THEN
                retcode := InsertTABLE4(RECORD2);
                IF (retcode = DATABASE_OK) THEN
                    UPDATE TABLE2
                    SET    TABLE2.Status = 20
                    WHERE  TABLE2.ID     = CURSOR2.ID;
                ELSE
                    ROLLBACK TO SAVE_LOOP;
                END IF;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
        IF (vError = 0) THEN
            UPDATE TABLE1
            SET    TABLE1.Status = 20
            WHERE  TABLE1.ID     = CURSOR1.ID
        ELSE
            ROLLBACK TO SAVE_LOOP;
            UPDATE TABLE1
            SET    TABLE1.Status = vError
            WHERE  TABLE1.ID     = CURSOR1.ID

            UPDATE TABLE2
            SET    TABLE2.Status = vError
            WHERE  TABLE2.ID     = CURSOR2.ID
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Small update:

I managed to do the validation set-based, though I don't really know how to get my data into the other table. I tried a insert select with the trim in it but that only inserts one row. If I would use a implicit cursor as suggested I still had to loop, I wouldn't loop the cursor but the SELECT INTO as far as the implicit cursor only has one row.

I guess I could really need a snippet or some link to help me out. Here's a simplified version of my try:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE3
(
  val1,
  val2,
  val3
)
SELECT TRIM(val1),
       TRIM(val2),
       TRIM(val3),
FROM   TABLE1
WHERE  STATUS = 10
AND    (TRIM(PK1) || TRIM(PK2)) NOT IN (SELECT (TABLE3.PK1 || TABLE3.PK2) FROM TABLE3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it is bad style to do things by looping in SQL.  A loop like this will be extremely slow compared to a set-based solution.  Instead of all these loops, it would be preferable to use a single `insert` or `merge` statement to copy all of table 1 into table 3--or perhaps a few statements if your validation is complex and you need some intermediate steps.

Most types of trimming and data validation you would want to do can be handled like this.  Almost never do you need nested loops.  There are exceptions, but they are rare.  Those who are new to SQL tend to use loops because that is what we know from other languages.  I was in that category not so long ago.  But to really use the power of the language, you have to get beyond that.

Beyond this general point, not much specific help can be given if we don't know anything about the tables or what kind of validation you are doing.

When you should `commit` is also dependent on your specific design and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Its about warehousesoftware, those data from TABLE1 and TABLE2 are coming from the HOST which could be SAP/BAAN etc. I have to trim the data and validate if its a known warehouseplace, if the unit is known, the address exists etc. so I have to check some other tables. I have to post them into our tables (different columnnames) and change some values (kg -> g, m -> cm). Won't be too much data so the speed shouldnt be a problem.

Comment: @user1900980, none of the steps that you describe would require looping.  If what you have now works, that is fine, but if you want to "learn the right way" you should try to get away from this type of design in the future.

Comment: Furthermore, if you really did have to use a cursor it would be preferable to use an implicit cursor rather than an explicit cursor. Less code, less to go wrong, and more performant in many circumstances.